# Javascript - why forEach method added duplicate item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Was trying to create a new array object based on the existing array key-value pair with the old one. But it returns me 22 items, whereas my old array is 20. Any clue?

I know old having duplicate and I wanted to keep it.

```js
var old = [
  "35189432",
  "35189424",
  "62617691",
  "62617802",
  "33637179",
  "33637152",
  "GRP00437",
  "38051474",
  "34775346",
  "63055352",
  "GRP07780",
  "GRP00436",
  "63055352",
  "68798876",
  "68798841",
  "66886255",
  "66911969",
  "67215974",
  "66886239",
  "67996399"
];

var next = [
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189432",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189424",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617691",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617802",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637179",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637152",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 110000,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "38051474",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "34775346",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "68798876",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "68798841",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
   
  },
  {
    
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
   
    "sku": "66886255",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
  
    "price": 1320000,
    "isNew": false,
  
    "sku": "66911969",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {
   
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67215974",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "66886239",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  
  },
  {
    
    "price": 44000,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67996399",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 84700,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "GRP00437",
    "selectedSku": "10769213",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 117700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP07780",
    "selectedSku": "33283601",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 135300,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP00436",
    "selectedSku": "12595816",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
  }
];

console.log('old-->', old);
console.log('next-->', next);
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
        data.forEach(item => {
            if (orderKey.toString() === item.sku.toString()) {
                products.push(item);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-console-output@0.8.5/dist/index.js"></script>
```

Any help?

Comment: If there are multiple items with a matching SKU, which one should be pushed to `products`?

Comment: @Barmar - is it possible to keep both? like, on first old (63055352) will keep first next(63055352) and on second on so loop keep next

Comment: If it keeps both then you get duplicates, don't you?

Comment: Looks into TJ's answer and I want like, OLD (63055352) - One will keep One of NEXT and OLD (63055352) two will keep TWO of NEXT and it can be more..

Comment: but the total item will same as the OLD array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using **nested** loops, meaning that the inner loop (on `data`) runs all the way through `data`'s elements for **each** iteration of the outer loop. So if more than one item in `data` matches during an iteration of the outer loop, you'll add multiple entries to `products`.

That happens with `sku` value `"63055352"`, which is in `old` twice and also in `next` twice. So those items end up being added to `product` twice, twice. :-) Here it is called out, and with some logging showing when it happens:

```js
var old = [
  "35189432",
  "35189424",
  "62617691",
  "62617802",
  "33637179",
  "33637152",
  "GRP00437",
  "38051474",
  "34775346",
  "63055352", // One
  "GRP07780",
  "GRP00436",
  "63055352", // Two
  "68798876",
  "68798841",
  "66886255",
  "66911969",
  "67215974",
  "66886239",
  "67996399"
];

var next = [
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189432",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189424",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617691",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617802",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637179",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637152",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 110000,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "38051474",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "34775346",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // One
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // Two
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "68798876",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "68798841",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
   
  },
  {
    
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
   
    "sku": "66886255",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
  
    "price": 1320000,
    "isNew": false,
  
    "sku": "66911969",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {
   
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67215974",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "66886239",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  
  },
  {
    
    "price": 44000,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67996399",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 84700,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "GRP00437",
    "selectedSku": "10769213",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 117700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP07780",
    "selectedSku": "33283601",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 135300,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP00436",
    "selectedSku": "12595816",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
  }
];

console.log('old-->', old);
console.log('next-->', next);
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
        let added = 0;
        data.forEach(item => {
            if (orderKey.toString() === item.sku.toString()) {
                products.push(item);
                if (++added > 1) {
                    console.log(`Item ${item.sku} pushed ${added} times so far in one iteration on ${orderKey}`);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-console-output@0.8.5/dist/index.js"></script>
```

> So, if I wanted to keep both pair, then what would be the solutions?
>
> Like, OLD (63055352) - One will keep One of NEXT and OLD (63055352) two will keep TWO of NEXT and it can be more...?

You'd have to keep track of which ones you've processed from earlier passes. You can also stop looking through `next` once you've found one, something like this:

```
function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
        const added = new Set();
        const itemToAdd = data.find(item => item.sku === orderKey && !added.has(item));
        if (itemToAdd) {
            products.push(itemToAdd);
            added.add(itemToAdd);
        }
    });

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var old = [
  "35189432",
  "35189424",
  "62617691",
  "62617802",
  "33637179",
  "33637152",
  "GRP00437",
  "38051474",
  "34775346",
  "63055352",
  "GRP07780",
  "GRP00436",
  "63055352",
  "68798876",
  "68798841",
  "66886255",
  "66911969",
  "67215974",
  "66886239",
  "67996399"
];

var next = [
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189432",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189424",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617691",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617802",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637179",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637152",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 110000,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "38051474",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "34775346",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // One
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // Two
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "68798876",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "68798841",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
   
  },
  {
    
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
   
    "sku": "66886255",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
  
    "price": 1320000,
    "isNew": false,
  
    "sku": "66911969",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {
   
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67215974",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "66886239",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  
  },
  {
    
    "price": 44000,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67996399",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 84700,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "GRP00437",
    "selectedSku": "10769213",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 117700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP07780",
    "selectedSku": "33283601",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 135300,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP00436",
    "selectedSku": "12595816",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
  }
];

console.log('old-->', old);
console.log('next-->', next);
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
        const added = new Set();
        const itemToAdd = data.find(item => item.sku === orderKey && !added.has(item));
        if (itemToAdd) {
            products.push(itemToAdd);
            added.add(itemToAdd);
        }
    });

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-console-output@0.8.5/dist/index.js"></script>
```

For what it's worth, you could use a `for-of` loop (and `const` instead of `var`), though you don't *have* to:

```
function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    for (const orderKey of orderedKeys) {
        const added = new Set();
        const itemToAdd = data.find(item => item.sku === orderKey && !added.has(item));
        if (itemToAdd) {
            products.push(itemToAdd);
            added.add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const old = [
  "35189432",
  "35189424",
  "62617691",
  "62617802",
  "33637179",
  "33637152",
  "GRP00437",
  "38051474",
  "34775346",
  "63055352",
  "GRP07780",
  "GRP00436",
  "63055352",
  "68798876",
  "68798841",
  "66886255",
  "66911969",
  "67215974",
  "66886239",
  "67996399"
];

const next = [
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189432",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189424",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617691",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617802",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637179",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637152",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 110000,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "38051474",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "34775346",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // One
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352", // Two
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "68798876",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "68798841",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
   
  },
  {
    
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
   
    "sku": "66886255",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
  
    "price": 1320000,
    "isNew": false,
  
    "sku": "66911969",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {
   
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67215974",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "66886239",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  
  },
  {
    
    "price": 44000,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "67996399",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 84700,
    "isNew": false,
    
    "sku": "GRP00437",
    "selectedSku": "10769213",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 117700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP07780",
    "selectedSku": "33283601",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
    
  },
  {
    
    "price": 135300,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP00436",
    "selectedSku": "12595816",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
  }
];

console.log('old-->', old);
console.log('next-->', next);
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = [];
    for (const orderKey of orderedKeys) {
        const added = new Set();
        const itemToAdd = data.find(item => item.sku === orderKey && !added.has(item));
        if (itemToAdd) {
            products.push(itemToAdd);
            added.add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }

    console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-console-output@0.8.5/dist/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to keep both pair, then what would be the solutions?

Comment: Like, OLD (63055352) - One will keep One of NEXT and OLD (63055352) two will keep TWO of NEXT and it can be more...? Can you help me on that?

Comment: is there any way do this?

Comment: @DanielSmith - I've added an example of doing that.

Comment: I had a similar question here, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058713/javascript-merge-array-and-keep-duplicate-based-on-main-array-key-value/64058820#64058820

Comment: On another post, I wanted to merge array with the same logic. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058713/javascript-merge-array-and-keep-duplicate-based-on-main-array-key-value/64058973?noredirect=1#comment113279863_64058973

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on `next` variable.
Checking the content, the sku of 9th and 10th item is same.
Both items' sku is `63055352` so that problem happened.

So `sku` is not unique on `next` variable, so duplicated items are added.
`product` variable contains duplicated `63055352` value and also `next` variable contains duplicated `63055352` sku products so you can see the differences.

Comment: can you check once again I have added on-site Stack Snippets.

Comment: Yeah, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are m x n items in total (while m = old.length, n = data.length). It will be pushed into products if only matches your condition. If you want to remove duplicated items, you should use Set instead of Array. e.g.

```
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
    const products = new Set();
    orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
        data.forEach(item => {
            if (orderKey.toString() === item.sku.toString()) {
                products.add(item);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log(...products);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested loops, just use `find()` to find the first item in `data` with a matching SKU, and push that.

```js
var old = [
  "35189432",
  "35189424",
  "62617691",
  "62617802",
  "33637179",
  "33637152",
  "GRP00437",
  "38051474",
  "34775346",
  "63055352",
  "GRP07780",
  "GRP00436",
  "63055352",
  "68798876",
  "68798841",
  "66886255",
  "66911969",
  "67215974",
  "66886239",
  "67996399"
];

var next = [{
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189432",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 107800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "35189424",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617691",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 161700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "62617802",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637179",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "33637152",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 110000,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "38051474",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 148500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "34775346",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 94600,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "63055352",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "68798876",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {

    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "68798841",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {

    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "66886255",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {

    "price": 1320000,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "66911969",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {

    "price": 41800,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "67215974",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false
  },
  {
    "price": 797500,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "66886239",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {

    "price": 44000,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "67996399",
    "isGroup": false,
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false

  },
  {

    "price": 84700,
    "isNew": false,

    "sku": "GRP00437",
    "selectedSku": "10769213",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,

  },
  {

    "price": 117700,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP07780",
    "selectedSku": "33283601",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,

  },
  {

    "price": 135300,
    "isNew": false,
    "sku": "GRP00436",
    "selectedSku": "12595816",
    "isPurchasable": true,
    "isLowInventory": false,
    "isIRExperience": false,
    "isGroup": true,
  }
];

console.log('old-->', old);
console.log('next-->', next);
getReorderedProducts(old, next);

function getReorderedProducts(orderedKeys, data) {
  const products = [];
  orderedKeys.forEach(orderKey => {
    let found = data.find(item => orderKey.toString() === item.sku.toString());
    if (found) {
      products.push(found);
    }
  });

  console.log('final products--->', products);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-console-output@0.8.5/dist/index.js"></script>
```